# Have I phrased this naturally?

Tags: idiomatic-language

I'm on my way to a party which has been underway for a few hours already.

***Lili is going to be at the party too.***

Is the above phrased naturally if I know that Lili already is at the party that I'm on my way to? Is "is going to be" correct? I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: If Loki is already at the party how about just saying “Lili is already at the party I am going to”?

Comment: The person "I'm" saying this to doesn't know that Lili is invited to the party.

Comment: If you are not yet at the party then "going to be" is good because it is the future in your time frame. Also, you might not know for sure if Lili is actually there, or already there (might be late, as you are).

Comment: If she is there already then she is there. She might have been invited, she might be there as a guest of someone who was invited, she might have crashed the party. In all cases the fact she is there is the salient fact. Perhaps the message you are trying to communicate is “We will see Lili at the party”. It’s hard to know what you are trying to communicate.

Comment: As @WeatherVane makes clear your phrasing suggests you don’t know if Lili is there or not. If you want that uncertainty to be part of the message then your phrasing is good. If you are sure she is there then it is not so good.

Comment: The discussion is not about the ultimate truth of the statement. The discussion is about the message intended to be communicated. The message may be false, it may be a deliberate lie. That is irrelevant for this discussion.

Comment: The title of this question is not very useful as it gives no indication what the question is about.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, "going to be" does not refer to the *party* as such, but instead *your experience of* the party.

"When I get to the party, I'm going to find that Lili is at the party too."

It's perfectly correct, even if you know that Lili is already there (because you've talked to her on her phone, maybe).

It says something very subtly different from "Lili is already there" -- it means that Lili is expected to *still be there* when I get there.

Comment: That is certainly one of the several possible intentions of using this phrase.